# How to properly use ViewPager in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, templating

I want to make a quiz application. So far I have 3 activities - home, quiz, score. Since the quiz activity contains multiple equivalent views ( image header, question and 4 answer buttons ), I did some reading and decided that 
`ViewPager` with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` show do the trick. So I made an `xml` template and inflated couple of test views and it was all looking good, until I started handling the user interaction.

I want to simulate a toggle button and there is only one correct answer to each question, so selecting one button should deselect the previous one ( if any ). When the button is pressed I change my `Question model`, then I find all 4 buttons with `findViewById` and reset their color filter. Then I set that filter back on my selected button. To determine which question model to update I use the current `fragment` position, which I have set ( using `setTag`, in fragment's onCreate ) in my template root view.

This is how I call my fragmets:

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
     Question question = Repository.findById(position);
     int correctAnswerBtnId;
     switch (question.getCorrectAnswerIndex()) {
         case 0: correctAnswerBtnId = R.id.quiz_answer_0_btn; break;
         case 1: correctAnswerBtnId = R.id.quiz_answer_1_btn; break;
         case 2: correctAnswerBtnId = R.id.quiz_answer_2_btn; break;
         case 3: correctAnswerBtnId = R.id.quiz_answer_3_btn; break;
    this.ACTIVITY_ROOT.setTag(question.getID());

    Fragment fragment = new QuestionFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(QuestionFragment.QUESTION, question);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
```

}

My QuestionFragment onCreateView is as per documentation:

```
public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container,
        Bundle questionData) {

    this.rootView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.layout_question_template,
            container,
            false);

    Bundle args = getArguments();
    this.question = (Question) args.getSerializable(QuestionFragment.QUESTION);
    populateInflatable();

    rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout_question_template_root).setTag(this.question.getID());
    return rootView;
}
```

In `populateInflatable` I use `this.rootView` to `fintViewById` and populate it with my question data. Then I change the color of a button, if there is selected one from the Question.

On button click I call `selectAnserButton` :

```
public void selectAnswerButton(View selectedButton) {
    int questionId =
            (int) this.activityRoot.findViewById(
                    R.id.layout_question_template_root).getTag(); //??
    unSelectAllButtons();
    changeColor(selectedButton);
    Repository.findById(questionId).selectAnswer(selectedButton.getId());
}
```

Where `unSelectAllButtons` represents `buttonToUnSelect.getBackground().clearColorFilter();` on the four buttons. and `Repository` is just a `static` class with example question data.

It all goes terribly wrong, when I have more then one view. On each fragment I inflate the same `xml` with same View IDs, as I have defined them. And as I now understand calling `findViewById` retrieves not one, but all views with that Id from my current, but also from my previous and next `fragment` as well. So every time I want to select my current `fragment`'s view, I also modify the same view in the previous and next `fragments` as well. You can imagine how this is problematic. This makes me feel I have a fundamental mistake, because I don't think there is supposed to be more then one `View` with same `ID`.

I really don't understand how I should do this using ViewPager. At this point it feels like I'm trying to make a wood carving, but instead I am hacking the framework to pieces. There must be a better way to do this with ViewPager.

**RESOLVED:** Thanks to Soo Chun Jung for pointing me to the answer. In short what got it working for me was:

1. Passing my `Question model` id to each fragment with `Bundle`.
2. Storing each fragment in inside an `ArrayMap` with fragment position as `key` and fragment as `value`.
3. Getting each individual fragment from my `selectAnswer` function is now easy: first get the current fragment's position with `myViewPager.getCurrentItem`, then calling `getter` function which returns a fragment on the current position.
4. Now that I have the fragment I can easily change its button's because they are kept as private fields, assigned in the 'onCreateView` method.

Comment: It'd be useful if you could show a [mcve]

Comment: `How to properly use ViewPager in android` - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html &
 https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: Also, it sounds like you need to learn about RadioButton.  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html

Comment: @MarkKeen Thanks for the link, but I have read the documentation. Otherwise I wouldn't be able to make it work at all.

Comment: @Gary99 RadioButtons will help, thanks for that. But they do not solve my fundamental problem. Which is how to target Views on my current visible fragment only.

Comment: This might help you https://medium.com/@khermaj/android-viewpager-implementation-6c48c868a0e8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it's helpful~

**adapter**

```
class CustomAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private final String[] TITLES = {"A", "B"};
private final String TAG = CustomAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

private final ArrayList<Fragment> mFragments;

private final FragmentManager fm;

public CustomAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    mFragments = new ArrayList<>(getCount());
    this.fm = fm;
}


@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return TITLES[position];
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return TITLES.length;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    Log.d(TAG, "destroyItem position = " + position);
    mFragments.remove(object);
    super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    Object object = super.instantiateItem(container, position);
    mFragments.add((Fragment) object);
    return object;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Log.d(TAG, "getItem position = " + position);
    if (position == 0) {
        return MyFragmentA.newInstance();
    } else if (position == 1) {
        return MyFragmentB.newInstance();
    }
    return null;
}

public MyFragmentA getMyFragmentA() {
    synchronized (mFragments) {
        for (Fragment f : mFragments) {
            if (f instanceof MyFragmentA) {
                return (MyFragmentA) f;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public MyFragmentB getMyFragmentB() {
    synchronized (mFragments) {
        for (Fragment f : mFragments) {
            if (f instanceof MyFragmentB) {
                return (MyFragmentB) f;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
} 
}
```

**Fragment class**

```
  public class MyFragmentB extends Fragment {

...


    public updateYourUI(){
        //update something
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
mPager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);


mAdapter.getMyFragmentB().updateYourUI();
```

for your comment below If you only have one kind Fragment. You can modify some function like this.

```
public static MyFragmentB newInstance(int ID) {
    MyFragmentB fragment = new MyFragmentB();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("ID", ID);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    myID = getArguments().getInt("ID");
    ....
}

public int getMyID() {
    return myID;
}





public MyFragmentB getMyFragmentByID(String id) {
    synchronized (mFragments) {
        for (Fragment f : mFragments) {
            if (f instanceof MyFragmentB) {
                MyFragmentB temp = (MyFragmentB)f;
                if(temp.getID.equals(id){
                    return (MyFragmentB) f;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I will give it a try as soon as I can. I don't understand why is `getItem` hardcoded for concrete amount of items? Also how can I use the Fragment instance to update my UI? That would solve a lot of issues, but I looked through `Fragment` docs as well and could not find an answer.

Comment: Just got an idea: If I set each fragment's UI views as his private fields inside the `onCreateView` method I can then access those via getters, after I access the current view fragment as you have shown. Would that work?

Comment: My problem however is that I have multiple instances of the same `Fragment`. So how can I distinguish between them? I need to set some sort of Id to the fragment itself.

Comment: Sorry I am not good at English. It might be making a misunderstanding. anyway I made my answer updated. please check.

Comment: Alright, using `Bundle`, of course. Thanks very much. I will try this as soon as I can sit down, and will mark as accepted when I get it working.

Comment: Cheers mate, it worked nicely. I had to make one adjustment, because in my case I don't know the Fragment ID, so I changed your fragmets List to Map with view position as key and used that to get my fragments. Thanks